# In convergence, why not $d \leq \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convergence-divergence

In defining convergence, one requires $d < \epsilon$ for some relevant "distance" $d$ and arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Why not $d \leq \epsilon$?

This still allows one to get arbitrarily close to (but not equal to) the limit. Given any tolerance, we can always get at least as close as that tolerance by taking (for example, in convergence of a sequence) $N$ large enough.

Using $d < \epsilon$ does seem more intuitive.

Comment: Either will do, it makes no difference.

Comment: I've seen convergence (or related concepts) defined with $d\leq \epsilon$ in my first calculus class. It was even an exercise to show it did not matter how it was defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent:

> **Theorem.** Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$ and let $x\in\Bbb R$. The following are equivalent:
>
> (1) For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.
>
> (2)  For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|\le\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.

*Proof.* That (1) implies (2) is obvious since if $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ then $|x_n-x|\le\epsilon$. Now suppose (2) holds. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then, $\epsilon/2>0$ so by (2) there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|\leq\epsilon/2$ for all $n\ge N$. But $\epsilon/2<\epsilon$, so $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ and hence (1) holds. This concludes the proof.

> **Definition.** If either of these hold we say that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ and write
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x.$$